# svn add files with names starting with particular character

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

Is there a command which can add all the files with names starting with a particular character to commit? Lets say, I want to add all the files with names starting with `a` to `commit`. Then, is there a single Linux command to achieve this?

Comment: Are the files all in the same directory? If so: `svn add a*`

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, buddy it worked. It just didn't strike in my mind to use * for matching the pattern.